# TypeError: done is not a function Passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

```
passport.use('local.signup', new Localstrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    roleField: 'role',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, email, password, role, done) {
    req.checkBody('email', 'Invalid Email').notEmpty().isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Invalid Password ').notEmpty().isLength({min:4});
    req.checkBody('role', 'Invalid Password').notEmpty();
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        var messages = [];
        errors.forEach(function(error) {
            messages.push(error.msg);
        });
        return done(null, false, req.flash('error', messages));
    }
    // what the...
    User.findOne({
        'email': email
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        if (user) {
            return done(null, false, {
                message: 'Email is already in use.'
            });
        }
        var newUser = new User();
        newUser.email = email;
        newUser.password = newUser.encryptPassword(password);
        newUser.role = role;
        newUser.save(function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            return done(null, newUser);
        });
    });
}));
```

Comment: Are those line-breaks in strings part of your original code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this setting will do anything:

```
roleField: 'role',
```

You can fix the error by changing your function arguments from this:

```
function(req, email, password, role, done) {
```

to this:

```
function(req, email, password, done) {
```

Comment: events.js:163
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: done is not a function
    at /Users/ZL/Desktop/nodeJs/debble/passport_config/passport.js:54:20
    at /Users/ZL/Desktop/nodeJs/debble/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3932:16

Comment: cause my Schema of user has the role, so maybe the role is necessary, i'm confused that why 'done is not a function' is it about Promise ?  hope u can help me ,i'm struggling almost one day

Comment: @conleywang It has nothing to do with promises. The function will be passed 4 arguments and the 4th argument is the `done` callback. By adding in a `role` argument you move `done` to 5th, which won't exist. Arguments are determined by position, not name. If you need extra information such as a role you'll need to get it from the `req` object yourself.